# Openstack - Selectively deleting images based on some criteria?

Tags: python, bash, openstack, openstack-nova, packer

We are creating openstack Images nightly with Packer. We want to keep the last 5 that we've created and automatically delete the rest. (Ideally delete them only if they have no instance running that is based on them, but indiscriminately is fine if that is not possible).

I have been looking through the documentation of the various Openstack APIs and I can't seem to find a neat way to do this.

What I was thinking of was running nova image-list and parsing that with bash, but this seems a bit finicky and a potentially dangerous way to do things when we're talking about auto-deletion.

The bash script would look something like this :

cross reference this:

```
nova image-list | grep "CentOS-7-x86_64 " | cut -d'|' -f 2
```

with this:

```
nova list | grep "ACTIVE" | cut -d'|' -f 2 | while read -r line ; do nova show "$line" ; done
```

But already this is stupidly unwieldy and it doesn't even do anything yet....

My question is, is there a better way to do this that I've missed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve this using the Python API rather than trying to solve this using the CLI tools.  Here is some code that will get you the necessary keystone, nova, and glance clients:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

import keystoneclient.auth.identity as keystone_identity
import keystoneclient.session as keystone_session
import keystoneclient.client as keystone_client
import novaclient.client as nova_client
import glanceclient.client as glance_client

auth = keystone_identity.v2.Password(auth_url=os.environ['OS_AUTH_URL'],
                   username=os.environ['OS_USERNAME'],
                   password=os.environ['OS_PASSWORD'],
                   tenant_name=os.environ['OS_TENANT_NAME'])

# establish a keystone session
sess = keystone_session.Session(auth=auth)

# get a keystone client
kc = keystone_client.Client('2',
                            session=sess,
                            auth_url=sess.auth.auth_url)

# and authenticate it
kc.authenticate(token=sess.get_token(),
                project_id=sess.get_project_id(),
                tenant_id=sess.get_project_id())

# get a nova client
nc = nova_client.Client('2', session=sess)

# get a glance client
gc = glance_client.Client('2',
                          endpoint=kc.service_catalog.url_for(
                              service_type='image',
                              endpoint_type='publicURL'),
                          token=sess.get_token())
```

Assuming that you have that available, you would first get a list of available images matching your criteria:

```
images = [img for img in gc.images.list()
          if 'CentOS-7-x86_64 'in img.name]
```

And then get the list of images you want to delete:

```
to_delete = images[5:]
```

Then get a list of images that are in use:

```
in_use = []
for server in nc.servers.list():
    in_use.append(server.image['id'])
```

And then delete everything that's not in use:

```
for img in to_delete:
    if img['id'] not in in_use:
        gc.images.delete(img['id'])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your answer :) I think you are right, that looks much simpler, I wasn't aware it was as simple as doing server.image['id']. Thanks very much for your help!